# Shadow Warrior Xbox One freezes on first launch

Tags: xbox-one, shadow-warrior

The first time I launched Shadow Warrior on my Xbox One, the game freezes when it prompts me to enter a profile name. The input is pre-filled with my gamertag (no special characters, just a space and letters). The keyboard doesn't appear, and if I press (A) the game freezes and quit.

*PS: I run the game with language set to French*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that for some reasons the game won't launch in French, and freezes on the profile popup.

The quick fix is to launch the game with the console language set to English.

To do that:

1. Go to settings and set language to 'english' (region doesn't matter)
2. Restart the console
3. The console will download a language pack (~50mo) and restart
4. Once the console is started in English launch the game
5. Now the game should launch without prompting you for a profile
6. Start a new game and save
7. (optional) You can reset your console language to 'French' (or whatever) and continue your game